# Unable to clear view inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an item say "bill" in  `Navigation Drawer`, When I click on a bill  I have opened a `Fragment` say `Fragment_A`, inside `Fragment_A` I have one `Viewpager` and `tab layout`.

Inside `view pager` I have two `Fragments` say `Fragment_1` and `Fragment_2`.

Inside `Fragment_1`, I have a Filter image on top(in `Actionbar`) by clicking on this button I have given the option to select a filter.

The problem is that when I am clicking first time on drawer item (bill), it is working fine but the second time onwards the view of `Fragment_1` is not getting cleared.

```
// I have written this code inside Fragment_A

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_bill_, container, false);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Bill"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Mybill"));    
            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

            ViewPagerAdapter adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
                {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });

            return view;

// This is my adapter class
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:

                return new Bills_Fragment();
            case 1:
                return new MyBill_Fragment();

                 }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        Log.d("position===","case2noone");
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: `view of Fragment_1 is not getting cleared` means?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Ke1k3    see this link

Comment: I am uploading this image here,first time when i am cliking  on paid then view is getting changed but second time it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Using this

---

> .notifyDataSetChanged()

---

You can change all data and reload data within your viewpager.
For destroying viewpager item use this method into viewpager adapter

```
 @Override 
           public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                   ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);  }
```

Comment: where I should write .notifyDataSetChanged() inside my viewpager adapter class